Distributing 3 distinct particles among 4 distinct energy states
Essentially, the question boils down to this: "Do we need to consider the order of distinct particles occupying the same energy level in a quantum system ?"
For further clarification, I have included the question (as taken from Reichl's Statistical mechanics) that inspired this post below:
If we consider the following state of the above mentioned system with energy 5:
$$\{|x_1x_2||x_3\}$$
Where, 2 particles occupy  the state $E_1$ with energy 1 and 1 particle occupies state $E_3$ with energy 3.
How many microstates would be associated with  the above state, 3 or 6 ? That is, would we consider $\{|x_1x_2||x_3\} \neq \{|x_2x_1||x_3\} $ for distinct particles ?
Just for some context the system can only have a total energy of 5, with the following energy levels:
$$
\begin{align}
E_0 &= 0 \\
E_1 &= 1 \\
E_2 &= 2 \\
E_3 &= 3 \\
\end{align}
$$
In the above question the $x$'s symbolize particles and each state is symbolized as being in between the $||$ the sticks.

For distinguishable particles there is no (anti-)symmetrization requirement, so the wave function would be a simple product of the individual particle states.

We don't have to consider order. The statistics work only if we don't. That's why it's said that particles are indistinguishable.

But what about distinct particles?

Than you do have to consider order. That's what distinguishability means.
